# Small JavaScript/jQuery mouseleave question

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mouseover, mouseleave

I got this small JavaScript using jQuery that slides down a ul when an image is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img.menu_class').click(function() {
$('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
});

});
```

I was wondering if I could modify it to recognize when the mouse leaves the ul/image and make it slide back instead of having the user click on the image again. If I use something else than click() it would (naturally) only apply to the image and won't recognize the ul as an object. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole code (added some image swapping to the whole thing), working at all major (updated) browsers at the moment. Not very clean and probably could be done easier but it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('ul.menu_body').hide();

if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {

    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        if ($('ul.menu_body').is(':hidden')) {

            $('ul.menu_body').fadeIn('medium');
            $('.menu_head').attr("src", "layout/buttonhover.png");
            $('.menu_body').css("font-weight","normal");


        } else if ($('ul.menu_body').is(':visible')) {  
            $('ul.menu_body').fadeOut('medium');
            $('.menu_head').attr("src", "layout/servbtn.png");
        }
    });

} else {

    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        if ($('ul.menu_body').is(':hidden')) {
            $('ul.menu_body').fadeIn('medium');
            $('.menu_head').attr("src", "layout/buttonhover.png");

        } else if ($('ul.menu_body').is(':visible')) {  
            $('ul.menu_body').fadeOut('medium');
            $('.menu_head').attr("src", "layout/servbtn.png");
        }
    });

    $('.dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
        if ($('ul.menu_body').is(':visible')) {
            $('ul.menu_body').fadeOut('medium');
            $('.menu_head').attr("src", "layout/servbtn.png");
        }
    });     

   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery [mouseout()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Comment: Yes, I played around with it. But I can't manage to make it work along with the click function unfortunately... :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

$('img.menu_class').bind('mouseleave',function() {
$('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
});

---

or

$('img.menu_class').bind('hover',function() {
$('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
});

---

Use this code.

**This is my updated code**

**Use this code to slidedown ur list once mouse hover on image and remains open**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('img.menu_class').bind('hover mouseleave',function() {
 $('ul.the_menu').slideDown('medium');
});

//to close ul

$('#id_of_close_element').bind('click',function() {
 $('ul.the_menu').slideUp('medium');
});

});
```

Comment: Both work fine, the problem is that they only recognize img.menu_class which makes the ul slide back when you move away from the image. That cancels the usability since you can't select anything from the list...

Comment: you can use multiply selectors you separate each selector with a comma